# In JavaScript, how can I access the id of setTimeout/setInterval call from inside its event function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

How can I access the process id of setTimeout/setInterval call from inside its event function, as a Java thread might access its own thread id?

```
var id = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(id); //Here
}, 1000);
console.log(id);
```

Comment: what process id? there is no separate process.

Comment: does setTimeout spawn a thread?

Comment: That code works as-is. @lelloman no, of course not. JS does not have threads.

Comment: It is the right way, it works well to me(but it is not a process). Anyway, **JavaScript !== Java**!

Comment: @MattBall :( I was about to celebrate

Comment: @lelloman if you want seperate threads for some reason, you've always got web workers.

Answer (score 14):

That code will work as-is, since `setTimeout` will **always** return before invoking the provided callback, even if you pass a timeout value which is very small, zero, or negative.

```
> var id = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(id);
  }, 1);
  undefined
  162
> var id = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(id);
  }, 0);
  undefined
  163
> var id = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(id);
  }, -100);
  undefined
  485
```

> Problem is I plan to have many concurrently scheduled anonymous actions, so they can't load their id from the same variable.

Sure they can.

```
(function () {
  var id = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(id);
  }, 100);
})();
```

Comment: Problem is I plan to have many concurrently scheduled anonymous actions, so they can't load their id from the same variable.

Comment: @user1636586 So push their ids into an array and iterate through the array to clear them.

Comment: @user1636586 there's a simple fix for that. See my edit.

Comment: Who's talking about clearing them? I just want to be able to announce these actions by id as they are run.

Comment: //It seems if I deploy my timers from different execution blocks I can get the result I want.
(function(){
 var id = setTimeout(function(){    console.log(id); }, 3000); console.log(id);
})();
(function(){
 var id = setTimeout(function(){    console.log(id); }, 2000); console.log(id);
})();
(function(){
 var id = setTimeout(function(){    console.log(id); }, 1000); console.log(id);
})();

Comment: @user1636586 that's precisely what I meant by my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to `setTimeout` is not aware of the fact in any way. And that's not a process id or thread id, just a weird API decision.

Comment: It's not a weird API decision at all. It's a handle for canceling the timeout later.

Comment: Yes it's not weird API that you can cancel all timeouts by doing `var l = 100000; while(l--) clearTimeout(l)`. Even with heaviest wrappers you can't fix it.