# Why is my for loop returning a strange number in the console

Tags: javascript, browser, closures, settimeout

I get a seemingly random number whenever I paste this code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(x) { return function() { console.log(x); }; }(i), 1000*i);
    // 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

into the console in chrome and firefox.  `258` in the below picture.  What is that number?

[image]

Comment: It also seems to add 5 each time... :/

Comment: That number would be the return value from the last `setTimeout()`.

Comment: shouldn't that be 5?

Comment: No, as in the number that the `setTimeout()` function returns, which is an ID that you can use with `clearTimeout()`. It has nothing to do with your loop counter. When you run code directly in the console, it prints the result of the last line of code executed (in addition to any explicit `console.log()`s, but in this case those happen later because of the timeouts).

Comment: i made with same code one [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2pmh5e8b/) , and give me 1,2,3,4,5. Could be from other code?

Comment: ahhh ok i see, thank you.

Comment: P.S. It's adding 5 each time because you call `setTimeout()` five times each loop, and usually those returned IDs are just one more than the previous one. (One way or the other they need to be unique, so that you can cancel a specific timeout.)

Comment: it also seems to continue to increment one every second... This is interesting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280375/in-javascript-how-can-i-access-the-id-of-settimeout-setinterval-call-from-insid